# Why is my VS Code's git indicator showing "(Rebasing)" next to the branch name?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-rebase

I'm having an issue with my vscode for git config. I believe `git pull` is set to perform merges by default. A couple weeks ago, I ran `git config pull.rebase true`, and since then, I keep seeing "(Rebasing)" next to my branch name. Like below:

[image: screenshot of "(Rebasing)" indicator]

I tried to revert it to default `git config` with `git config pull.rebase false`, but it's not working at all.

Why is this happening (is something wrong?), and how can I get it back to normal?

Comment: Sounds like you started a rebase and didn't finish. show us the output of running `git status`. If you're in the middle of a rebase and want to abort it, use `git rebase --abort`.

Comment: "I believe `git pull` is set to perform merges by default." That wouldn't explain the `(Rebasing)` status, that would show `(Merging)`.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you started a rebase and didn't finish. If you're in the middle of a rebase and want to abort it, use `git rebase --abort`. Otherwise, you should be able to see files that still need conflicts resolved in the Source Control view with a "UU" indicator next to them. Then you can find them, fix them, and run `git rebase --continue`.

Answer (score -1):

To prevent `pull` from attempting to auto-merge, run the following command to update your global git config:

```bash
git config --global pull.ff only
```

This may result in a failed `pull` especially on a shared branch, but it's easy enough to do a `rebase` at that point or a `pull -r`.

I would also turn off the auto-rebase feature:

```
git config --global pull.rebase false
```

Both these things will cause git to act more predictably when there's divergent branch history.